# Намерения Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы после ввода даты и нажатия кнопки открывалась другая активность, в которой показывается результат. То есть в дочерней активности поле для ввода даты, а в другой активности только результат. Я никак не могу додуматься, как это правильно реализовать

```
private void startSubActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, SubmainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult (intent, SHOW_SUBACTIVITY);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEditText = (ETView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               startSubActivity();
           }
         });        
}
```

Вот другая активность

```
    public class SubmainActivity extends MainActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    private ETView mEditText;
    private TView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_submain);

        mTextView = (TView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

                   Date date = new Date();
                   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                   try{
                        String str_date= mEditText.getText().toString();
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                        date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
                        c.setTime(date);
                           Log.d(TAG, date.toString());
//                         int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                           String s3 = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
//                         String s3 = String.valueOf(dayOfWeek);
                           mTextView.setText(s3);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            mTextView.setText("Дата введена неверно");
                        }

               }
             };
}
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("date", date);

Comment: Тогда нужно будет в дочерней активности добавить date?

Answer (score 2):

Перед `startActivityForResult` необходимо добавить

```
intent.putExtra("DATE", mEditText.getText().toString());
```

Во второй активности в методе onCreate:

```
String date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATE");
```

**Обновление**

Можете заменить у себя

```
String str_date= mEditText.getText().toString();
```

на мою строку, т.е. в вашем случае будет

```
String str_date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATE");
```

**Обновление 2**

Поменяйте на `String str_date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATE");`.

Comment: Во второй активности добавить или заменить?

Comment: Потому что если добавить
 
    String date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATE");

то он сразу начинает конфликтовать с 

    Date date = new Date();

Comment: поменяйте на String str_date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATE");

Comment: Как бы я не написал дату в поле ввода, он говорит "Дата введена неверно"

Comment: Возможно, ошибка в формате, в котором ты вводишь дату. Посмотри в логах или на дебаге, передается ли строка.